# Subscribe error: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular

I am learning to use Services in angular and I have problems to subscribe to my component. What am I doing wrong?

I poll with some amounts but none of them worked

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Tweet } from '../Models/tweet';
import { TweetService } from '../Services/tweet.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-twitter',
  templateUrl: './twitter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./twitter.component.css']
})
export class TwitterComponent implements OnInit {

  tweet: Array<Tweet>;

  constructor( private tweetService : TweetService) {
    this.tweetService = tweetService;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tweetService.getListTweet()
      .subscribe((data : Array<Tweet>) => {
        this.tweet = data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

This is my service, I do not know, if here is the problem or in the component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TweetService {

  baseUrl: string = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
   }

   getListTweet(){
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/posts`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, translate the question to English

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Tweet } from '../Models/tweet';
import { TweetService } from '../Services/tweet.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-twitter',
  templateUrl: './twitter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./twitter.component.css']
})
export class TwitterComponent implements OnInit {

  tweet: Array<Tweet>;

  constructor( private tweetService : TweetService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tweetService.getListTweet()
      .subscribe((data : Array<Tweet>) => {
        this.tweet = data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

Service:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class TweetService {

      baseUrl: string = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
       }

       getListTweet(): Observable<any>{
        return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/posts`);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject them only in your constructor if u want more information you can check https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection. Basically once when i provide it as argument to your constructor you have reference to you service and you are able to call all props/methods from this reference. No need attach reference in your components to them.